# How to set dynamic data-title in ngtable (angular plugin)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ngtable

I want have a multi language view with an ngTable. For do that, i set in my controller a $scope.translate (a valid json) who contains my traductions. In my view i want set my data-title like {{translate.code}} etc...

my view :

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table ng-table-responsive">
        <tr ng-repeat="product in $data">
            <td data-title="'{{translate.code}}'" > <!-- display : {{translate.code}} -->
                {{product.code}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="['translate.reference']" > <!-- display : empty -->
                {{product.reference}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Label'" >
                {{product.label}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Size'" ng-show="manageSizeColor == true">
                {{product.size}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Quantity'" >
                <ac-quantity minquantity="1" cquantity="product.quantity"></ac-quantity>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Price'">
                <b>{{product.price + currency}}</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I' ve finally found how do this, with this example :
https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/53

```
<td data-title="translate['reference']" >
   {{product.reference}}
</td>
```

where translate is the scope variable and ['reference'] is the property

Answer (score 13):

If you're using `angularjs ~1.2` with `angular-translate ~2.6.1`, translation on `data-title` works like this:

```
<td data-title="'MY_TRANSLATION_ID' | translate" >
{{product.reference}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this :

```
<td data-title="getColumnName('your.translate.code')">{{ resultat.number }}</td>
```

with in your controller :

```
$scope.getColumnName = function(column) {
    return $translate.instant(column);
}
```